# UWP - How to properly recycle items in ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm presenting a heterogeneous data array in `ListView` by listening to `ChoosingItemContainer` event. Everything works fine, except for item recycling: `ListView` keeps suggesting wrong container type (it's a list with "load more" functionality, so "load more" item is always on top of recycle queue each time  loading is complete). Is there a way to pull another container from `ListViewBase`'s recycle queue or at least remove currently suggested container from recycle queue, so I can additionaly manage my own tag-based recycle bin and another container will appear next time?

`ChoosingItemContainer` example at Microsoft site suggests something like own recycle bin, but it's rather cryptic what's "relevantStorage" is and how to remove non-matching recycled containers from `ListViewBase` so they stop reappearing each time.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, you should additionally listen to a separate `ContainerContentChanging` event which not only drives presentation phases, but also notifies about item recycling. Everything works as expected now (well, almost as expected: instead of immediately reusing disappearing list items, ListView keeps a huge supply of ~100 items onscreen - and sometimes recycle queue is empty despite that; sometimes it requests a handful of items from start of the list while list view is scrolled to the end; etc. - but, generally, it works well). Here's an example usage:

```
private void HandleContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args) {
    if (args.InRecycleQueue) {
        if (item.Tag is string itemType) {
            _recycleBin.EnqueueItemWithType(itemType, item); // NOTE Do your own book-keeping here
            args.Handled = true; // NOTE Handle event only in case of recycle to prevent breaking x:Phase bindings
        }
    }
}
```